# awk finding a column and trimming

Tags: regex, awk, filter

I have a text file with irregular structure like following

```
first_name1 last_name1 designation1 email1 phone_number1
first_name2 last_name2 designation2 email2
first_name3 last_name3 designation3 email3 phone_number3 address3
```

As you see email could be the last column, second last column or the third last column. This means one simply cannot use $NF to get email. My goal is to get email address wherever it is on the line and then extract the portion before @ so for instance email1 = foobar@dept.company.com then I want to extract foobar. How can i write an awk query to extract first portion of the email address. I tried this but it is looking for exact match. How can i make it into Regex to get the job done.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i=="foobar@dept.company.com"){print $i} } }' users.txt
```

Comment: Is email always the fourth column? (If so, just use `$4`)

Comment: @e0k No. Email could be anywhere on the line

Comment: Do you expect multiple emails per line?

Comment: @e0k. Just one. Please see  above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing `$i` to a string `"foobar@dept.company.com"`, so yes of course this will only make an exact comparison.  What it seems you are looking for is whether or not `$i` matches (`~`) a regular expression (`/.../` instead of `"..."`), then tailor the regex to your needs.  Try something like:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){if ($i ~ /.+@.+/){sub(/@.*$/, "", $i); print $i; next}}}'
```

The regex `/.+@.+/` matches a string with a `@` in it, and some non-empty thing before it and after it.  This will *not* match, for example `@foobar` or `foobar@`, or just `@`.  You might want to consider using something more like `/.+@.+\..+/` which would match *(something)*`@`*(something)*`.`*(something)* since domain names usually have a `.` in them.  You can tailor this regex to be more specific, if you wish.

The `sub(/@.*$/, "", $i)` means to substitute in `$i` everything after (and including) the first `@` until the end of the line (`$`) with an empty string `""`, thus stripping out the part before the `@` (i.e. the username).  The `print $i` prints it, and the `next` moves on to the next line (skipping any remaining fields for the current record).

Comment: Thanks so much. It really helped

Comment: Keep in mind that using a simple regex like this to identify a well formed email address is only a very rough estimation. For a more general (and more correct) solution, you would need to check many more factors, for example that the username and domain name use only the correct characters, that there is no more than one `@` in the field, etc.  Hopefully you have no other fields with `@`, or you might get false positives. I would only use something like the above for a one-off use if it's on my own file and I have a high confidence of the formatting, etc.

Comment: `/^[[:alnum:]._%+-]+@[[:alnum:].-]+\.[[:alpha:]]{2,}$/` would be much more robust - ref http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know awk at all but I looked the regex reference up and this should be supported: [`\b([^ ]*@.*?)($|[^\w@.])`](https://regex101.com/r/RxzN35/1) in which group 1 matches the email. This just search for something after a word boundary that contains `@`. The match ends at the next non word character, excluding `@` and `.`.

Comment: No, that will not be supported by any standard UNIX tool. Testing a regexp on some web site is practically useless - a regexp is only useful inthe context of the tool(s) that can use it.